# merge items in a list which are part of string

Tags: python, list, algorithm, for-loop

I am trying to iterate over a list (LST) to find if an item contains a substring (SUBSTR). Post that I have to check the surrounding elements to see if they all together are part of another string (MNSTR). For eg.

```
LST = ["ITEM1", "ITEM2", "ITEMWV3", "ITEM4", "ITEM5"]
SUBSTR = "WV"
MNSTR = "BLAH something ITEM1 xyzpqr ITEM2 ITEMWV3 ITEM4 abcde ITEM5"
OUT = "ITEM2 ITEMWV3 ITEM4"
```

I'm implementing this using 3 for loops and I believe there must be a much better way to do this.

1. First for loop to iterate over list (LST)
2. Check if SUBSTR is present in an item, if yes then initiate another for loop going backwards
3. Keep on picking each item until no match is found. After this OUT will have "ITEM2 ITEMWV3"
4. Start going forward from the first match until no match is found.
5. After this the OUT will have "ITEM2 ITEMWV3 ITEM4"
6. After both the inner for loops execute, break and return the results

The items in list will always be in order they exist in the main string (MNSTR). My target is to reduce the number of for loops and also reduce the line of code. Can someone please help with this.

Comment: Please include the code you are trying to optimize, preferably as a [mre]

Comment: Its a very lengthy and bad code and will greatly increase the length of the question. Thats why I converted it into a pseudocode and posted it along with initial and final state. Also, I read somewhere it is better to provide pseudocode in such situations, thats why I didn't post it. Still if you want, I'll clean it up and post it.

Comment: The description is open to interpretations "surrounding elements", "all together are part of another string" are not very precise descriptions. It would be good if you could at least provide a few more examples, covering some of the boarder cases (e.g. with more than 3 words matched, ...)

Comment: Can someone please upvote it to get me out of negative votes. I updated the question and also got the answers needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only 1 for loop is needed:

1. Loop to iterate over list (LST)
2. Check if SUBSTR is present in an item, if yes then get the item before and after
3. Build "item-1 item item+1" (OUT)
4. Check if that is a substring of MNSTR

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in 3 lines of code :

I didn't fully understood what you want to do here but if it is what i think it is that should help you out :

```
for Item in LST:
    if SUBSTR in Item:
        return f'{SUBSTR} is in {Item}'
```